# how to change the bootstrap sortable table head pseudo elements position

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-vue

I'm working with a bootstrap-vue component: sortable table. you can find the example [here](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/).

My question is, how to move the arrows (they are actually pseudo elements of the `th`) from the end of the `th` to right next to the `th` content. only by css and may be html.

Since every content length is not same, I can not simply use a absolute position to the arrows.

[image]

Comment: Because the upwards arrow is created using ::before, you can’t just remove the absolute positioning to get the elements in normal flow, you would end up with "↑ Label ↓". But flexbox and its `order` property can help ... If that messes up the rest of the layout (when display:flex is applied to the TH), you would have to insert another container element first though.

Comment: thank @CBroe I don't want to move the arrow to the front and end. I just want to move both of them right behind the label, not at the end of each th container.

Comment: I know that you don't _want_ that, I said that's where their position in normal flow would be, so you have to do something about that - something else than absolutely position them, because that is incompatible with wanting them to be wherever the text ends. Again, flexbox/order can help.